# Select available dates using Microsoft Playwright for .NET NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, playwright-test

I'm trying to do a test using Playwright for .NET NUnit. I would like to select the available dates without having to write them in the code (e.g. the first 3 available days)
Hire is my code:

```
public async Task Test()
        {
            await Page.Context.Tracing.StartAsync(new()
            {
                Screenshots = false,
                Snapshots = true,
                Sources = false
            });

            await Page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new() { Name = "Create Account" }).ClickAsync();
            
            await Page.GetByPlaceholder("First Name *").FillAsync("Jonh");
            await Page.GetByPlaceholder("Last Name *").FillAsync("Smith");
            await Page.GetByLabel("Choose Tuesday, August 1st, 2023").ClickAsync();
            await Page.GetByLabel("Choose Saturday, August 5th, 2023").ClickAsync();
            
            await Page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new() { Name = "Submit" }).ClickAsync();

            // Stop tracing and export it into a zip archive.
            await Page.Context.Tracing.StopAsync(new()
            {
                Path = "trace.zip"
            });
        }
```

The example of the calendar with de available dates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO3JH.jpg)

Thanks!

I tried writing the dates in the code and it works fine, but I would like to make an abstraction since the enabled dates can change